# for loop, expect and pssh

Tags: for-loop, ssh, expect

I need a script to modify the same data in multiple servers. For now the for loop generate the command lines, but i'm experiencing some problems with expect and pssh.

The for loop:

```
<code>
    for ((var1=1;var1<=14; var1++))
    {
      cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
        for ((var2=1;var2<=8;var2++))
        {
          cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
            for ((var3=1; var3<64; var3++))
            {
              cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
            }
        }
    }
</code>
```

I'm using pssh instead ssh in expect script.

The full code:

```
<code>

    #!/usr/bin/expect

    set timeout 20

    set ip [lindex $argv 0]
    set user [lindex $argv 1]
    set password [lindex $argv 2]

        for ((var1=1;var1<=14; var1++))
{
  cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
    for ((var2=1;var2<=8;var2++))
    {
      cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
        for ((var3=1; var3<64; var3++))
        {
          cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
        }
    }
}        
    spawn pssh "$user\@$ip"

    expect "yes/no" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
            } "*?assword" { send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
            expect "SH"

    interact
</code>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
<code>
wrong # args: should be "for start test next command"
    while executing
"for ((var1=1"
    (file "./ssh" line 9)
</code>
```

Comment: Not clear what your question is? what are the problems you're experiencing? It'll be helpful to clarify it both in the headline and the header

Comment: Hello Amittai Shapira, the problem is the for loop in a expect script. The expect stops working or don't work.

Comment: You probably need to add more information - when did it stopped working? what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops in expect and Tcl have to look like this:

```
for {set var1 1} {$var1<=14} {incr var1} {
    commands...
}
```

In other words, the `for` command *requires* **four** arguments: the start code, the condition, the "next" code and the loop body. Note that newlines are command separators in Tcl, so the open brace for the loop body **must** be on the same line as the `for` command (or you must use a backslash-newline line continuation).

You used bash/ksh syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax error in for loop, there's a logical problem with the code snippet in the question:

- var2 isn't available for printing in the outermost loop (for the first time).
- var3 isn't available for printing in the 2nd loop (for the first time).

Here's probably what you need:

```
for {set var1 1} {$var1 <=14} {incr var1} {
    puts "LEVEL_1: $var1"
    # cda stm add "$var1" ss 1
    for {set var2 1} {$var2 <=8} {incr var2} {
        puts "LEVEL_2: $var1/$var2"
        # cda stm add "$var1/$var2" ss 1
        for {set var3 1} {$var3 <64} {incr var3} {
            puts "LEVEL_3: $var1/$var2/$var3"
            # cda stm add "$var1/$var2/$var3" ss 1
        }
    }
}
```